# Application is working or not

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

How should I know if an application is working or processing something? Lets say that I'm trying to write a huge data into a file, on that time the application is not responding. I want to know the application current status.

Comment: You application should be multi-threaded and provide it's own feedback. Otherwise there isn't any real way. If the GUI thread is hung then even windows might mistake the application as "Not responding"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) componenet to process huge data in background thread. Notify user about progress via [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event.

Sample:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    }

    private void WriteDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfIterations; i++)
         {
             // write part of data
             backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 100 / numberOfIterations);
         }    
    }

    // This event handler updates the progress. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(
                object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    // This event handler deals with the results of the background operation. 
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
                object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Huge data was written");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1567051 no problem :) I have updated sample a little. Btw you can drag backgroundWorker from tool box to your form and subscribe to events from designer.